# Print a list that is stored in a variable in LUA

Tags: lua

My script uses `lfs` to read files in a directory.
It then stores the value in a variable called `file`.
The problem is the value is actually a list.
Here is a sample value.

```
.
..
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

I can print this variable as is, but I need to integrate this variable inside a dialog box.
When I integrate this variable inside a dialog box, it prints each line in a new dialog.
Here is my code:

```
require 'lfs'

function main()
    for file in lfs.dir[[C:\Users\QXJtaW5pdXM\Desktop\Test\test_3.4.5.6]] do
    print(file)
    --This works perfectly fine.

    Dialog("Title", "Files:\n" .. file)
    --This prints each line in a new dialog box.
    end
end

return main
```

I need to print all the files in one dialog box.
If at all possible, I'd love to avoid printing `.` & `..`

As a picture reference, here is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Y4m.jpg

Here is what I need:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieoVX.jpg

Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `table.insert` in a for loop to add values inside a table `file_list`.
Then use `table.remove` to remove the first two inputs `.` & `..`

In the end, the code would look something like this:

```
require 'lfs'

file_list = {}

function main()
    for grab_files in lfs.dir[[C:\Users\QXJtaW5pdXM\Desktop\Test\test_3.4.5.6]] do
        table.insert(file_list, grab_files)
        -- table.insert will assign each input of grab_files into each reference of file_list table
    end
    table.remove(file_list,1)
    -- This removes the '.'
    table.remove(file_list,1)
    -- This removes the '..'
    file_names = table.concat(file_list, "\n")
    Dialog("Title", "Files:\n" .. file_names)
end

return main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop's body is executed once for every file so what do you expect if you create a dialog inside the loop? Create it outside after you've created a list of files.

```
require 'lfs'

function main()
    local files = ""
    for file in lfs.dir[[C:\Users\QXJtaW5pdXM\Desktop\Test\test_3.4.5.6]] do
      files = files .. file .. "\n"
    end
    Dialog("Title", "Files:\n" .. files)
end
```

Maybe there is also another function that gives you a list of file names right away.